# I want itertools to return a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm using `itertools` to generate all possible permutations of a list. I would like it to return a list of lists, but this is not what I'm getting.

For example

```
import itertools
print list(itertools.permutations([1, 2]))
```

returns

```
>>> [(1, 2), (2, 1)]
```

But I was expecting

```
>>> [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Just curious : why?

Comment: No, it's not possible. `itertools.permutations` simply doesn't produce lists but tuples. There's no way to request lists instead. You'll have to convert them to lists if you really need that.

Comment: @EricDuminil, I, for example, need to add an element to each tuple to query a pandas DataFrame,  df[tupple + [1]]. Basically, I need a list of all possible permutations that also contains another element... and I need to do this many many times... and I want to avoid converting tuples to lists (I read is an O(n) operation), or joining dataframes is expensive... ideas are welcome of how to circumvent this case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just map your tuples to lists:

```
import itertools
try:
    # Python 2, use Python 3 iterator version of map
    from future_builtins import map
except ImportError:
    # already using Python 3
    pass

map(list, itertools.permutations([1, 2]))
```

In Python 3, `map()` is an iterator too, so the tuples are converted to lists as you iterate.

I'm assuming here that you don't need the full permutations result in one go. You can always call `list()` on the `map()`, or use a list comprehension instead if you do:

```
[list(t) for t in itertools.permutations([1, 2])]
```

or for Python 2, just drop the `from future_builtins` import and leave `map` to produce a list.

Comment: Yes but `map` does not return a list of lists

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: Just call `list()` on the `map()`. I'm erring on the side of saving memory.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a list comprehension to convert each tuple to a list and collect the results in a list:

```
>>> [list(p) for p in itertools.permutations([1, 2])]
[[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```